# how to prevent layout shift on button click in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I am creating Drawer example . I am following this link
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/

Everything work as expected .But I am facing one issue when my drawer open **my content shift to right and when it close it come to remain to it's original position** .It's look bad as layout is shifting when drawer opens.Is there any way to prevent .I saw example here the layout is not shifting example (https://codesandbox.io/s/j9je2v?file=/demo.tsx) . can we create drawer like this

**Expected Behavior** : **Drawer should not shift layout**

here my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-hooks-5jcjym?file=/demo.tsx:1545-1568

```
const drawerWidth = 240;

const openedMixin = (theme: Theme): CSSObject => ({
  width: drawerWidth,
  transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
  }),
  overflowX: "hidden"
});

const closedMixin = (theme: Theme): CSSObject => ({
  transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
  }),
  overflowX: "hidden",
  width: `calc(${theme.spacing(7)} + 1px)`,
  [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
    width: `calc(${theme.spacing(8)} + 1px)`
  }
});

const DrawerHeader = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  display: "flex",
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "flex-end",
  padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
  // necessary for content to be below app bar
  ...theme.mixins.toolbar
}));

interface AppBarProps extends MuiAppBarProps {
  open?: boolean;
}

const AppBar = styled(MuiAppBar, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "open"
})<AppBarProps>(({ theme, open }) => ({
  zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
  transition: theme.transitions.create(["width", "margin"], {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
  }),
  ...(open &&
    {
      // marginLeft: drawerWidth,
      // width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
      // transition: theme.transitions.create(["width", "margin"], {
      //   easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      //   duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
      // })
    })
}));

const Drawer = styled(MuiDrawer, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "open"
})(({ theme, open }) => ({
  width: drawerWidth,
  flexShrink: 0,
  whiteSpace: "nowrap",
  boxSizing: "border-box",
  ...(open && {
    ...openedMixin(theme),
    "& .MuiDrawer-paper": openedMixin(theme)
  }),
  ...(!open && {
    ...closedMixin(theme),
    "& .MuiDrawer-paper": closedMixin(theme)
  })
}));
```

**Current behaviour**

[image]

**Expected behavior** : Drawer doesn't shift layout .It comes over the text
[image]
any suggestion ?

Expected output simpler to

Answer (score 0):

Just adding position:fixed to const Drawer did the trick

> `const Drawer = styled(MuiDrawer, { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "open" })(({ theme, open }) => ({ width: drawerWidth, flexShrink: 0, whiteSpace: "nowrap", boxSizing: "border-box", position: "fixed", ...(open && { ...openedMixin(theme), "& .MuiDrawer-paper": openedMixin(theme) }), ...(!open && { ...closedMixin(theme), "& .MuiDrawer-paper": closedMixin(theme) }) }));`

[image]

[image]

[image]